# How to train a Deep Reinforcement Learning Network?

Tags: dataset, reinforcement-learning

This is a conceptual question. I come from a Computer Vision background where the Object Detection DNNs are trained using a predefined dataset such as COCO, NYU-D etc and then the DNN is able to predict the results for an input image based on the training.

However, in the case of Deep Reinforcement Learning I am unable to find a dataset that can train Deep RL networks. Rather I find resources that talk about environment for training.

So the questions is whether Deep RL networks are required to be trained using environments only or is it possible to train them similar to Object Detection DNNs i.e by using some sort of dataset ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common confusion in the AI community. Long story short, reinforcement learning (RL) method requires feedback (reward,state) from environment based on the action determined by RL. dataset is not able to provide that feedback. You can consider RL as a close-loop feedback system, whereas suerpervised learning (DNN) as the open-loop feedforward system.

To help you understand RL better. RL methods learn from the interaction with environment incrementally in the following steps:

1. Initialize RL agent policy and/or value functions;
2. Initialize the state that RL agent is starting with;
3. RL agent determines an action based on current state;
4. Action is applied to the environment;
5. Environment reacts to the action and state is updated, a reward is generated;
6. state and reward from the environment are transmitted to the RL agent;
7. RL agent updates its policy and/or value functions based on the state and reward feedback;
8. Then go back to step #3;

I suggest you to briefly read the RL text book from Richard Sutton: Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction. You can download free from here: https://web.stanford.edu/class/psych209/Readings/SuttonBartoIPRLBook2ndEd.pdf

Comment: So I have already taken the David Silver's RL course which is based on the book you mentioned. But just to confirm, what you are saying is that we cannot train RL using image based datasets? Right? We need to train them in an environments like Gym

Comment: DRL is not *a networ*, it is a learning paradigm that assumes environment, period. You can frame various problems in this language but it is very much a definition of reinforcment learning.

Comment: @ashah, right! To use RL do some image related task, you can read the DQN paper from DeepMind, where they train RL to play Atari Games. The input is image from game screen, reward is the score and action is character control. Another example is end to end DRL for autonomous driving. The input is the image capture from car camera, output is the steering angle, pedal positions. Both video games and Car are from simulation environment. Just not able to train RL using static image based dataset without dynamic environment.